# generate eos keys from Mnemonic/Seed

Tags: keys

I use this way to generate eos keys:

```
const hdkey = require('hdkey')
const wif = require('wif')
const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')
const bip39 = require('bip39')
const mnemonic = 'real flame win provide layer trigger soda erode upset rate beef wrist fame design merit'
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedHex(mnemonic)
const master = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(Buffer(seed, 'hex'))
const node = master.derive("m/44'/194'/0'/0/0")
console.log("publicKey: "+ecc.PublicKey(node._publicKey).toString())
console.log("privateKey: "+wif.encode(128, node._privateKey, false))
```

result:

```
publicKey: EOS61oRAVkx1rqPM8mEsBZxPAFAa9Nm6kLa7mQs6mRKTsRTFQaad7
privateKey: 5KX4T16FtxG9LvRJukA31TP9BKq3jYve3xQ3Px3ui8mzuJ7nUYE
```

With the new keys,I will update the EOS public key mapping to my Ethereum Wallet following this [article](https://steemit.com/eos/@sandwich/how-to-update-the-eos-public-key-mapped-registered-to-your-ethereum-wallet-with-myetherwallet-mew).

So my question is, what different between this way and [EOS Token Generator](https://nadejde.github.io/eos-token-sale/)?

Answer (score 1):

Mnemonic is a standard of bip39 for you to manage all chain private keys with a single master seed, so it's just a method to generate the private key, you can specify any private key you'd like if you don't want to use that standard.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "what is different"? The process you described above is correct for generating the EOS pub/priv key pair.

As for the site you linked, it appears they are using https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc for the generation, which should provide the same/similar results.